# Selecting all the previous 6 months data records from occurrence of a particular value in a column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to select all the previous 6 months records for a customer whenever a particular transaction is done by the customer.
Data looks like:

```
Cust_ID Transaction_Date Amount Description
1         08/01/2017        12       Moved
1         03/01/2017        15        X
1         01/01/2017         8        Y
2         10/01/2018         6       Moved
2         02/01/2018        12        Z
```

Here, I want to see for the Description "Moved" and then select all the last 6 months for every Cust_ID.

Output should look like:

```
Cust_ID   Transaction_Date   Amount    Description
    1         08/01/2017        12       Moved
    1         03/01/2017        15        X
    2         10/01/2018         6       Moved
```

I want to do this in python. Please help.

Comment: so `08/01/2017` 08 is the date and 01 is the month ryt?

Comment: Why is there row with Description "X" in expected resultset for Description "Moved"? Where's your attempt?

Comment: There is only one `Moved` per groups?

Comment: @anky_91 yes right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is created `Series` of `datetimes` filtered by `Moved` and shifted by `MonthOffset`, last filter by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) values less like this offsets:

EDIT: Get all datetimes for each `Moved` values:

```
df['Transaction_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction_Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['Cust_ID','Transaction_Date'])
df['g'] = df['Description'].iloc[::-1].eq('Moved').cumsum()

s = (df[df['Description'].eq('Moved')]
        .set_index(['Cust_ID','g'])['Transaction_Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthOffset(6))

mask = df.join(s.rename('a'), on=['Cust_ID','g'])['a'] < df['Transaction_Date']
df1 = df[mask].drop('g', axis=1)
```

---

EDIT1: Get all datetimes for `Moved` with minimal datetimes per groups, another `Moved` per groups are removed:

```
print (df)
   Cust_ID Transaction_Date  Amount Description
0        1       10/01/2017      12           X
1        1       01/23/2017      15       Moved
2        1       03/01/2017       8           Y
3        1       08/08/2017      12       Moved
4        2       10/01/2018       6       Moved
5        2       02/01/2018      12           Z

#convert to datetimes
df['Transaction_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction_Date'])

#mask for filter Moved rows
mask = df['Description'].eq('Moved')
#filter and sorting this rows
df1 = df[mask].sort_values(['Cust_ID','Transaction_Date'])
print (df1)
   Cust_ID Transaction_Date  Amount Description
1        1       2017-01-23      15       Moved
3        1       2017-08-08      12       Moved
4        2       2018-10-01       6       Moved
```

---

```
#get duplicated filtered rows in df1
mask = df1.duplicated('Cust_ID')
#create Series for map
s = df1[~mask].set_index('Cust_ID')['Transaction_Date'] - pd.offsets.MonthOffset(6)
print (s)
Cust_ID
1   2016-07-23
2   2018-04-01
Name: Transaction_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

#create mask for filter out another Moved (get only first for each group)
m2 = ~mask.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
df1 = df[(df['Cust_ID'].map(s) < df['Transaction_Date']) & m2]
print (df1)
   Cust_ID Transaction_Date  Amount Description
0        1       2017-10-01      12           X
1        1       2017-01-23      15       Moved
2        1       2017-03-01       8           Y
4        2       2018-10-01       6       Moved
```

EDIT2:

```
#get last duplicated filtered rows in df1
mask = df1.duplicated('Cust_ID', keep='last')
#create Series for map
s = df1[~mask].set_index('Cust_ID')['Transaction_Date'] 
print (s)
Cust_ID
1   2017-08-08
2   2018-10-01
Name: Transaction_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

m2 = ~mask.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
#filter by between Moved and next 6 months
df3 = df[df['Transaction_Date'].between(df['Cust_ID'].map(s), df['Cust_ID'].map(s + pd.offsets.MonthOffset(6))) & m2]
print (df3)
   Cust_ID Transaction_Date  Amount Description
3        1       2017-08-08      12       Moved
0        1       2017-10-01      12           X
4        2       2018-10-01       6       Moved
```

Comment: It's a good one, but it will fail in some cases if we have multiple `Moved` events. I've updated my example with the case when this approach doesn't work (see Update). In my example with your code we would display the `2017-03-01` event, although it doesn't precede any `Moved` record with a 6 months window (next `Moved` is `2017-10-01`)

Comment: @perl - ya, it depends what op need. Unfortuantely filtering per groups is possible, but slow...

Comment: I think I found a way that's both quick (I only have to `bfill` the grouped data) and handles these cases correctly. Updated my answer with that

Comment: @jezrael Hey, 1 last question...in the above scenario if i have to pull 6 months future data...what all i have to do in "EDIT" code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik - I think only need change `- pd.offsets.MonthOffset(6)` to `+ pd.offsets.MonthOffset(6)`

Comment: @jezrael I tried that but it is giving results with 0 observations in it

Comment: @jezrael Should i have to refer "EDIT2" ?

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik - exactly, first part of solution is like EDIT1, only last paragrapf is from EDIT2